# How to make variable change upon pressing on the RadioButton in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I have a program, where the user must sign up and in the sign up scene he picks gender with the RadioButton:
[Screenshot of the program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4gjf.jpg)

I have a variable "gender" which is a char; I want the program to change this char to either 'm' or 'f' depending on what RadioButton user presses('m' for male, 'f' for female).
This is what I have for now, but it does not work:

```
            @FXML
            private RadioButton male;
            @FXML
            private RadioButton female;
            private char gender;


            male.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    gender = 'm';
                }
            });
            female.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    gender = 'f';
                }
            });
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: What doesn't work? Where does it not work? Is there an error?

Comment: @Steven gender returns as null, regardless of the RadioButton pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `isSelected()` method associated with the `RadioButton` class.

For example,

```
if(male.isSelected()){
   gender = 'm';
}
```

Similarly, you can use it for the other radio buttons after proper initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a legend!

Answer (score 1):

Your radio buttons should be placed in a [ToggleGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html).

Without a toggle group, the radio button selection won't be mutually exclusive, so a gender could be both male and female at the same time.

Then, you can listen for changes to the selected toggle and act on it.  This can be done either by adding a listener to each toggle in the group:

```
male.selectedProperty.addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    if (isSelected) {
        gender = 'm';
    }
};
// similarly for female...
```

Or by listening to changes to the selectedToggleProperty of the group:

```
ToggleGroup genderGroup = new ToggleGroup();
male.setToggleGroup(genderGroup);
female.setToggleGroup(genderGroup);
genderGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(
   (observable, oldToggle, newToggle) -> {
       if (newToggle == male) {
           gender = 'm';
       } else if (newToggle == female) {
           gender = 'f';
       } else {
           gender = '?';
       }
    }
);
```